# vb or c#: start second project in process and kill it when first process exits - how find second exe?

Tags: c#, vb.net, process, named-pipes

In Visual Studio 2013, it is trivial to set two projects to start up at same time, as two processes.

But to deploy, I need to have one process (A) start the other (B). And then when A exits, it needs to stop B.

I see System.Diagnostics.Process class and example. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.process

But not sure (1) how to know what path to find B on. (2) where in A to put the code to stop B.

More details:

A is a 64-bit WinForms application targeting .Net 4.5.1. (Written in VB, but an answer showing C# is equally useful.)

B is a .Net wrapper around a 32-bit mixed-mode DLL targeting .Net 3.5. The wrapper source is mine; the DLL does not have source. (It is a third-party library that is no longer supported, with no 64-bit equivalent.) (Being mixed-mode, and originally 2.0, it complains if attempt to target newer than .Net 3.5.)

Communication is via Named Pipes.

It is a client (A) / server (B) situation, but there is only one client: (B) exists only as part of (A). (B) is separated only because (A) needs to be 64-bit and (B) is mixed-mode 32-bit (originally .Net 2.0) with no source available and no vendor support to get it rebuilt.

*** UPDATE ***

Re "(2) where in A to put the code to stop B" -- I figured out that since it is a WinForms, I make a custom Close to override the default window Close method.

So all I am missing now is understanding what path to put for B.  I have a solution with both projects in them. Each project is in a sub-folder. Is there an easy way to get (B) to copy its exe over to (A)'s bin folder?  Or some other approach to locate (B)'s exe?

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to have the two projects' .exe files in the same place (so that the path to 2nd exe is very simple): In each project, in project properties, under Compile options, change output directory (or path) from "bin" to "..\bin". Since the two projects are sub-folders of one solution, the resulting "bin" folder is in their parent's folder -- the .exes both end up in that parent "bin" folder.